# Write each column from each stock prices - R Studio

Tags: r, stock

Here are the codes I start:

```
mdate <- "2016-01-04"
edate <- "2016-03-09"
tickers <- c("ABG","ACH","ADM","AEG","AEM","AGQ","AGRO","AKOb","APO","ARCO","ASA") # actual tickers should be more than 2000

for(ticker in tickers)
  High_Raw <- cbind(High_Raw, getSymbols(ticker, from = mdate, to = edate, auto.assign = F))
```

As you expected the matrix shows 
      Open_ABG,    High_ABG,    Low_ABG...... Open_ACH,    High_ACH....and so on.

I want to organize these data like;
    Open_ABG,    Open_ACH...  Open_ASA,         High_ABG,    High ACH....    High_ASA,       Low_ABG.....   and so on

I know that I can use a code;

```
High_Raw <- cbind(High_Raw, getSymbols(ticker, from = mdate, to = edate, auto.assign = F))[,2] 
Low_Raw <- cbind(Low_Raw, getSymbols(ticker, from = mdate, to = edate, auto.assign = F)[,3]
```

but, there are errors; High_Raw contains 50 tickers and Low_Raw has 100 tickers because of errors. Since I try to import more than 2000 companies' data, this way wouldn't work for this.

What can I do to do this?

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. I guess the function `getSymbol` is not base R. Could you specify the package you are you using? I would also suggest [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example)  post to help us help you.

Comment: Also, we don't have `High_Raw`

Comment: The package is quantmod and High_Raw is a new one that stores those stock data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't grow your objects in `for` loop. Use `lapply` :

```
library(dplyr)
library(quantmod)

tickers <- c("ABG","ACH","ADM")

data <- do.call(cbind.data.frame, lapply(tickers, function(x) 
               getSymbols(x, from = mdate, to = edate, auto.assign = F)))
```

You can then use :

```
data %>% 
  select(contains('Open'), contains('High'), contains('Low'), contains('Close'))

#           ABG.Open ACH.Open ADM.Open ABG.High ACH.High ....
#2016-01-04     66.2     7.87     36.1     67.3     7.91 ....
#2016-01-05     66.7     7.94     35.8     67.1     7.95 ....
#2016-01-06     63.8     7.82     35.7     63.8     7.88 ....
#2016-01-07     56.2     7.40     34.9     57.7     7.52 ....
#2016-01-08     55.8     7.62     34.8     56.5     7.64 ....
#2016-01-11     53.6     7.37     34.5     55.9     7.39 ....
#....
```

You could also include `'Volume'` and `'Adjusted'` if you want them in final output.

Comment: Wow! that's perfect! Thank you so much!

Comment: Could you see my another question? I explained a little bit wrong in this page. I'll be really appreciate if you can help me out.